# Button That Opens (switches to) Different Product Detail Tab - Magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, button, tabs

I am using Magento Community, and there are product detail tabs on each products listing page. I have created a Make Offer form and put this in a product detail tab. I have a "make offer" button right under the "add to cart" button. I want this "make offer" button to have a function that directs the buyer to the Make Offer tab below (which is NOT currently opened to) by scrolling down the page and opening this product tab.

How would I do this?

Please let me know if additional information is needed.

Thanks!

Comment: how were you able to do authentication in magento i am struck ? could you help me out

Answer (score 0):

To "direct" the buyer to that specific area in the page you could use an achor pointing to the specific div using the id:

`<a href="#make-offer-tab-container" onclick="openMakeOfferTab()">Make Offer</a>`

To open the tab you would have to add some JavaScript (either in a .js file included in the page or in a template file). If you know how the tabs js works, you could reuse some code. If not you can trigger the click using jQuery or something similar:

```
function openMakeOfferTab(){
    jQuery(".make-offer-tab").click();
}
```